# Where local IIS is saving login and Registering User from Asp.Net Core (2.0 & 2.2)

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I create a new clean project, In VS.2017 everything run well, but when i publish into my local Windows 10 IIS

I can  register or login user (but no show name or this options:)

- HttpContext.User.Identity.Name not working in IIS
- SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)  not working in IIS

I look into my Database and users created are not there, but if I tried try recreate them register option say they already exists.

All the code is by default except the connection 
appsetting.jon

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DataCenter;Initial Catalog=ContaOnPrueba;User Id=Pavel;Password=MyPassWord21;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may not enable the windows auth and disable the anonymous auth in the IIS.

I suggest you could open the IIS management console to check the authentication settubg.

[image]

Make sure you have enable the windows auth and disable the anonymous auth.

[image]

Result:

[image]